# Cant resolve fs, net, tls after mysql installation

Tags: javascript, react-redux, redux-saga, mysql-connector, react-boilerplate

I have react-boilerplate application. I want to start using database so I installed:

```
npm install mysql   
npm install mysqljs/mysql
```

As shown in mysql webpage: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Now I get errors when I go to localhost in a browser:

```
 Can't resolve 'fs' in '....node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences'
 Can't resolve 'net' in '....node_modules\mysql\lib'
 Can't resolve 'tls' in '....node_modules\mysql\lib'
```

I am using redux-saga combination. 
I figured out that I get the error when I write:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
```

in saga.js file

How can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a MySQL client library within a browser app.

The errors you're seeing is the client library attempting to `require()` Node.js standard libraries for file system, network and encryption (TLS) access, which don't exist in the browser.

Comment: So what do I do? Previously with codemash.io database everything worked. I was getting my data in saga.js file, putting it into a state and everything was fine. Cant I simply switch to mysql and do the same simple thing?

Comment: No, you can't, since MySQL doesn't speak HTTP(S) or Websockets, which are (for this purpose anyway) the only protocols your browser can speak. You'll need a backend service that connects to MySQL.

Comment: So maybe there are database for front enders? Maybe MONGO db?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. What's the reason for switching away from Codemash, if it worked?

Comment: Good question. It was free and now they are making it paid :(

Comment: Well, Google's Firebase has a free tier, if it helps. It's accessible from the frontend.